# Установить картинку на фон textArea

Tags: java, javafx

Добрый день,пишу легкий чатик, захотел сделать приятный интерфейс, и при попытке поставить картинку на фон textArea столкнулся с проблемой отсутствия таковой возможности. Для графического составляющего использую Scene Builder.
Могу взять ImageView растянуть по всей textArea и подрегулировать opacity. Но теряется резкость выводимого текста. Подскажите пожалуйста, какие есть решение данной проблемы ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью [Scenic View](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) можно выявить внутреннюю структуру `TextArea`:

```
TextArea styleClass="text-input text-area"
  ScrollPane styleClass="scroll-pane"
    StackPane styleClass="viewport"
      StackPane
        ContentView styleClass="content"
          Group
            Text styleClass="text"
          Path
    ScrollBar styleClass="scroll-bar"
      ...
    ScrollBar styleClass="scroll-bar"
      ...
    StackPane styleClass="corner"
```

Исходя из этого, можно задать фоновое изображение в .css-файле в `.text-area {...}`, а внутренним панелям назначить прозрачность. При этом изображение не будет прокручиваться вместе с текстом:

```
.text-area {
    -fx-background-image: url("bg.png");
}

.text-area .scroll-pane .scroll-bar {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

.text-area .viewport {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.text-area .content {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.text-area .text {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian,#fff,10,0.8,0,0);
}
```

Если же нужно, чтобы изображение прокручивалось, тогда следует указать его в `.text-area .content {...}`.

*Документация по CSS:*

[JavaFX 9 CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

[JavaFX 8 CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, частично я понял, что Area имеет несколько слоев которые можно редактировать, мы поставили картинку и Content и Viewport сделали прозрачными. Я хотел бы подробней с этим ознакомиться, установил 
Scenic View 9 версию (9 jdk) но что-то она у меня не находит javaFx приложений. Или для того что бы посмотреть составные приложения нужно его создать ? (поместить в jar(ник) ?
Нашел еще один способ но он для NetBeans а я использую intellij idea. Какой способ вы использовали для установки Scenic View ?

Comment: Scenic View проще всего вызвать прямо в приложении `stage.show(); ScenicView.show(scene);`. Другие способы описаны на страничке помощи Scenic View (http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/help/)

Comment: не понял про какую именно программу вы говорите.
Если про Scenic View то она у меня открывается в таком виде, и постоянно пытается найти проекты https://ibb.co/nK9aBc.
а в меню file есть только закрытие программы

Comment: Имеется в виду то, что `scenicView.jar` сначала подключается к проекту в Intellij Idea — для этого я обычно создаю папку "Lib" в корне проекта, кидаю туда этот scenicView.jar, и, кликнув по нему правой кнопкой мыши, в контекстном меню выбираю "Add as Library...". Затем ScenicView запускаю прямо из своего JavaFX-приложения, например, сразу в методе `start()`.

Comment: Вродебы  сделал все как вы написали, получилось добавить scenicView.jar  к intellij idea но при компиляции появляются ошибки https://ibb.co/cNnqBc

Comment: В 8-ой версии все нормально. Это баг в 9-ой версии: https://bitbucket.org/scenicview/scenic-view/issues/27/exception-at-startup-cssfxtab-java-9 (там есть прицепленная пропатченная версия).

Comment: Скачал, и заменил, все заработало =) . Спасибо за помощь, извините что тупил ). Будем смотреть как это работает. еще раз Большое Спасибо =)